# Full outer join on a table itself and run some window functions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**Background**

I have some ETL job processing real-time log files hourly. Whenever the system generates a new event, it will take a snapshot of all historical event summary (if exists) and record it together with the current event. Then the data is loaded into Redshift.

**Example**

The table looks like something below:

```
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------+
| current_id | current_time | past_id | past_time | freq1 | freq2 |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------+
|          2 |        time2 |       1 |     time1 |    13 |     5 |
|          3 |        time3 |       1 |     time1 |    13 |     5 |
|          3 |        time3 |       2 |     time2 |     2 |     1 |
|          4 |        time4 |       1 |     time1 |    13 |     5 |
|          4 |        time4 |       2 |     time2 |     2 |     1 |
|          4 |        time4 |       3 |     time3 |     1 |     1 |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

This is what happened for the above table:

1. time1: event 1 happened. System took a snapshot, but nothing is recorded.
2. time2: event 2 happened. System took a snapshot and record event 1.
3. time3: event 3 happened. System took a snapshot and record event 1 & 2.
4. time4: event 4 happened. System took a snapshot and record event 1, 2 & 3.

**Desired Outcome**

I will need to transform the data into the following format in order to do some analysis:

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| id | event_time | freq1 | freq2 |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
|  1 |      time1 |     0 |     0 |
|  2 |      time2 |    13 |     5 |  --     13 |     5
|  3 |      time3 |    15 |     6 |  -- 13 + 2 | 5 + 1
|  4 |      time4 |    16 |     7 |  -- 15 + 1 | 6 + 1
+----+------------+-------+-------+
```

Basically, the new freq1 and freq2 are cumulative sum of lagged freq1 and freq2.

**My Idea**

I am thinking of a self `full outer join` on **current_id** and **past_id** and achieve the following result first:

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| id | event_time | freq1 | freq2 |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
|  1 |      time1 |    13 |     5 |
|  2 |      time2 |     2 |     1 |
|  3 |      time3 |     1 |     1 |
|  4 |      time4 |  null |  null |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
```

Then I can do a window function of `lag over()` and then `sum over()`.

**Question**

1. Is this the correct approach? Is there a more efficient way to do this? This is just a small sample of the actual data, so performance could be a concern.
2. My query is always returning a lot of duplicated values, so I am not sure what went wrong.

---

**Solution**

Answer from @GordonLinoff is correct for the above use case. I am adding some minor updates in order to get it working on my actual table. The only difference is that my **event_id** are some 36-character Java UUID and the **event_time** are timestamp.

```
select distinct past_id, past_time, 0 as freq1, 0 as freq2
from (
    select past_id, past_time,
           row_number() over (partition by current_id order by current_time desc) as seqnum
    from t
) a
where a.seqnum = 1
union all
select current_id, current_time,
       sum(freq1) over (order by current_time rows unbounded preceding) as freq1,
       sum(freq2) over (order by current_time rows unbounded preceding) as freq2
from (
    select current_id, current_time, freq1, freq2,
           row_number() over (partition by current_id order by past_id desc) as seqnum
    from t
) b
where b.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you want `union all` along with window functions.  Here is an example:

```
select min(past_id) as id, min(past_time) as event_time, 0 as freq1, 0 as freq2
from t
union all
(select current_id, current_time,
        sum(freq1) over (order by current_time),
        sum(freq2) over (order by current_time)
 from (select current_id, current_time, freq1, freq2,
              row_number() over (partition by current_id order by past_id desc) as seqnum
       from t
      ) t
  where seqnum = 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your data is in your snapshot table, I think the following SQL should give you what you are looking for in the desired outcome that you posted

```
SELECT 1 AS id
      ,"time1" AS event_time
      ,0 AS freq1
      ,0 AS freq2
 UNION
SELECT T.id 
      ,T.current_time AS event_time
      ,SUM(T.freq1) AS freq1
      ,SUM(T.freq2) AS freq2
  FROM snapshot AS T
 GROUP
    BY T.id
      ,T.current_name
```

The first `SELECT` in the above `UNION` is so that you can get the first record for `time1` since it does not really have an entry in your base table which holds all the snapshots.. It does not have a `FROM` in it since we are only selecting variables, if Redshift does not support it you might need to look for something equivalent to the `DUAL` table in Oracle.

Hope this helps..